# setDataAsync() causes error when inserting into Lists with Word Online

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I've recently noticed that when I attempt to set the value for a binding in Word Online for a selection of text that is a part of a bulleted list, numbered list, or multilevel list using the `setDataAsync()` method, I get the following error:

```
code: 5001 message: An internal error has occurred
```

Here is the code that I am trying to run (where `bindingId` is the binding ID of an already created binding within the document):

```js
Office.select(`bindings#${bindingId}`).setDataAsync(
    'test', { coercionType: 'text' }, (asyncResult) => {
        if (asyncResult.status === 'failed') {
            console.error(asyncResult.error.message);
        }
        console.log('success');
    }
);
```

The way to reproduce this is by creating a numbered or bulleted list in a document in Word Online, and select some text that is part of one of the bullets or numbered items. Then create a binding for that selection using this code:

```js
Office.context.document.bindings.addFromSelectionAsync(
    'text', (asyncResult) => {
        if (asyncResult.status === 'succeeded') {
            console.log('success');
        } else {
            console.error('failed');
        }
    }
);
```

After the binding is created, you can try to set the binding's value to something using the `setDataAsync()` code from above. This will generate the `An internal error has occurred` error.

Thanks in advance for any insight!